# Calling a specific action in a controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a controller with 2 actions like these:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("xyzlogin")
public class XyzloginController 
{
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) 
    {
         //.... do something....
    }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/requestXYZ", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView requestXYZ(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) 
    {
         //.... do something with parameter param1.
    }    
}
```

In a view file I have the following ways to request an action in this controller:

```
<a href="requestXYZ?param1=abc">Click me to call requestXYZ action</a>
```

As noted in the example above, upon clicking the hyperlink, I want to call requestXYZ action, but I am getting a 404 error instead, saying that it cannot find the mapping.

Am I defining the mapping wrong? What is the correct mapping?

Thanks,

Comment: Which URL are you at when (before) you click the link?

Comment: I am at this URL:
http://localhost:8080/authenticate/authorize/login?param1=abc

Comment: where "login" mapped to "LoginController.java"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a non-absolute (ie. doesn't start with `/`) path in your `href` attribute, the browser will append it to your current context. For example, if you are currently at `localhost:8080/yourapp`, clicking

```
<a href="requestXYZ?param1=abc">Click me to call requestXYZ action</a>
```

would send you to

```
localhost:8080/yourapp/requestXYZ?param1=abc
```

In your case, you are on

```
localhost:8080/authenticate/authorize/login?param1=abc
```

so clicking the link sends you to

```
localhost:8080/authenticate/authorize/requestXYZ?param1=abc
```

which obviously (almost) doesn't exist.

You can provide a leading `/` to the `href` string to make the browser construct a URL from your host address.

You should build your paths from your application context root

```
<a href='<c:url value="/xyzlogin/requestXYZ?param1=abc" />'>Click me to call requestXYZ action</a>
```

Where `c` is the `core` tag library. The above will create

```
localhost:8080/yourcontextroot/xyzlogin/requestXYZ?param1=abc
```

*Spring has its own tag for this as well.*